# What is the purpose of double slashes between two urls

Tags: html, url

I hope this isn't a dumb question but I came across this in a webpage and I am not sure what this means.

Here is the line of code I am referring to:

```
http://www.cnn.com/http://z.cdn.turner.com/cnn/tmpl_asset/static/www_homepage/2596/css/hplib-min.css
```

What is the purpose of the the first part of this link.  Why not just use the the second part, which is the actual pointer to the css file?

Comment: Probably a mistake of a developer

Comment: I've s.een this in a lot of websites, so I don't think its a mistake

Comment: Chris, it's definitely a mistake, I can assure you.  Lots of websites make lots of mistakes.  They're just pre-pending their base URL on the front of resources, and forgot to not do that for this particular URL.  If they wanted to use a URL in a URL like that, the colon `:` would have to be encoded as `%3A`.

Comment: Well I just checked the CNN.com home page. I got the CSS file referenced without the malicious "prefix" `http://www.cnn.com/`. If you see this repetedly, this might be an error of your browser or source code inspector.

Comment: Sorry, I am not explaining well.  What I mean is that there are two urls separated by a single slash.  If I paste this link into a browser I do in fact get a 404 error, but if I paste the second part of the url I can retrieve the file.

Comment: @Lukas, Could be a mistake they noticed fairly quickly and fixed... maybe the fix hasn't been replicated out to all the servers yet.

Comment: Ok, I was using FF and thats the output I got; but when I dumped the same page with IE everythink looks ok.  I guess its a FF thing.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a double slash between two urls. It is parsed as one (odd*) URL which in fact resolves to a 404 error.

Either this is done in error, e.g. because a templating system automatically appends the base URL, or (less likely) this is an attempt to defeat adblockers, by having the link come down with the base url, and javascript then massage it, and presumably load the resource afterwards.

`*` Brad, in comments argues that it is invalid. Maybe so (I'm not convinced), but in practice browsers will properly encode it for transmission.

Comment: It's clearly broken HTML for loading an ad or template or something.

Comment: @Brad Yes. As I say, it's a 404. It is, however, a valid URL - or at least, chrome will transmit the request to cnn.com, and cnn.com comes back with a 404.

Comment: It's definitely not a valid URL.  `:` is a reserved character that must be encoded.

Comment: @Brad It needs to be encoded on transmission. It doesn't need to be encoded in the html document.

Comment: Of course it does!  It isn't valid without it being encoded.  Sure, you can probably get away with it on most browsers, but it **is not valid** as-is.

Comment: @Brad I'm far from convinced of that. If you want to go spelunking through the HTML standards, feel free, but I'm not going to do it.

Comment: You're wrong.  If you choose to be wrong, I guess there is nothing to I can do to convince you.  For anyone else, it's plain as day in RFC1738.  http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Comment: "Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning:
   their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
   designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
   reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";",
   "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
   reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may
   be reserved within a scheme."

Comment: @Brad That document is not dispositive without reference to the applicable html standards. You're just telling me what I told you - it needs to be encoded for transmission.

Comment: HTML has nothing to do with URL encoding.  Otherwise, we would be talking about `&` => `&amp;` and such.  Using HTML doesn't magically change a completely different standard.

Comment: @Brad Let me break this down for you: the standard you cited governs the valid form of a url. However, it does not follow that the `href` attribute of a link must be a valid url not requiring encoding unless the html standard so prescribed. If html prescribed that all urls must be expressed with backslashes, that would be the only valid way to represent them in html.

Comment: @Brad is right. The HTML specs state that the href attribute value needs to be an RFC 3987 IRI reference. There is no arguing about how those are formed.

Comment: @Marcin, Now I understand the confusion.  I don't disagree that a URL can be encoded in another form.  (Obviously, since I was talking about HTML entities in a previous comment.)  My argument is that there is no unambiguous way to decode a URL with invalid uses of reserved characters to a valid one.  The browser is nice to us and it works in most cases, but should not be relied upon.

Comment: @Marcin the HTML spec of your choice. My example here is current [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/link.html)

Comment: None of this argument is necessary. It is a standard but it does not mean user agents do not behave differently or attempt to handle invalid input gracefully.

Comment: @uchuugaka My answer does say that.